# webpack error ENOENT, no such file or directory

Tags: css, node.js, webpack

We're using webpack in our project (Node.js, server-side only no browser) and bundle everything into a single JS file.

There's a Node package, `bhttp`, which I installed and it depends on the `errors` package. The `errors` package has some static files (CSS and HTML) and they don't seem to be packaged with the compiled/bundled code. So when I run my code, I get this error:

```
"errorMessage": "ENOENT, no such file or directory '//static/error.css'"
```

The `errors` package loads two static assets/files: `/static/error.css` and `/static/error.html` like this in the code:

```
errorCss = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/static/error.css', 'utf8');
errorHtml = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/static/error.html', 'utf8');
```

My webpack configuration file is:

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var webpack = require('webpack');

function readDir(filePath, upload, besePath, result) {
  result = result || {};
  besePath = besePath || filePath;

  fs.readdirSync(filePath).forEach(function (filename) {
    var currentPath = path.join(filePath, filename);
    var stat = fs.statSync(currentPath);
    var dest;
    var packageConfig;

    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
      return readDir(currentPath, upload, besePath, result);
    }

    if (filename === 'handler.js') {
      dest = currentPath.replace(filename, 'index');

      try {
        fs.accessSync(currentPath.replace(filename, 'config.json'), fs.R_OK);
      } catch (e) {
        return;
      }

      packageConfig = require(currentPath.replace(filename, 'config.json'));

      if (upload && packageConfig.upload !== true) {
        return;
      }

      dest = dest.replace(path.resolve(besePath + '/'), '');
      result[dest] = currentPath;
    }
  });

  return result;
}

module.exports = function (options) {
  options = options || {};

  var onlyWithUploadFlag = options.upload;
  var env = options.env || 'dev';
  var distFolder = options.dist || 'dist';

  return {
    entry: readDir(path.resolve(__dirname, './functions'), onlyWithUploadFlag),
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, distFolder),
      library: '[name]',
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
      filename: '[name].js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015'],
            plugins: ['syntax-flow', 'transform-flow-strip-types']
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          loader: 'json'
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      root: [
        path.resolve('./')
      ],
      modulesDirectories: ['/', 'common', 'node_modules']
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          BUILD_ENV: '"' + env + '"'
        }
      })
    ],
    externals: {
      'dynamodb-doc': true,
      'aws-sdk': true
    }
  };
};
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

(I'm new to webpack and can't seem to figure out how to package these static files with the bundle.)

Thanks.